# jQuery get json values

Tags: jquery, json

I'm trying to fetch the last **3 blog posts with the draft = false** for my system via jQuery json and following some tutorials if found online but without luck, and with the following keys:

"slug"
"updated"
"title"
"content"
"draft = false"

Here is the json output

```
{  
  "posts":[  
      {  
         "Blog":{  
            "id":"1252",
            "client_id":"1432",
            "slug":"my-blog-slug",
            "last_updated_by":"614",
            "draft":false,
            "created":"2014-09-17 11:18:39",
            "updated":"2014-09-17 11:18:39",
            "locale":"isl",
            "title":"This is the blog title",
            "content":"<p>My excellent content.<\/p>",
            "author":"John Doe"
         },
         "UpdatedBy":{  
            "id":"614",
            "name":"John Doe"
         }
      }
   ]
}
```

My current script is below, but i'm pretty sure that i'm doing a lot of things wrong.

```
<script>

    $(document).ready(function() {

            $.ajax({
                url: "blogs.json",
                dataType: "text",
                success: function(data) {

                    var json = $.parseJSON(data);
                    $('#results').html('Title: ' + json.created + '<br />Description: ' + json.content);
                }
            });

    });
</script>

<div id="results"></div>
```

Any help would be so much appreciated.

Comment: posts is array so to access first item you need to use index for example: $('#results').html('Title: ' + json.posts[0].Blog.created + '<br />Description: ' + json.posts[0].Blog.content); or loop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this way:

```
JS

$(document).ready(function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: "blogs.json",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(data) {
            var json = $.parseJSON(data);
            $.each(json.posts, function(){
                $('#results').html('Title: ' + this.Blog.title + '<br />Description: ' + this.Blog.content);
            });
        }
    });
});
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/bte8LdcL/)**

Answer (score 0):

Try this : posts is first key in json object and there could be multiple so access it using index, here it is zero. after getting posts, access each element by its key.

```
 var blog = json.posts[0]["Blog"];

 $('#results').html('Title: ' + blog["created"] + '<br />Description: ' + blog["content"]);
```

**EDIT** - as per OP comment, adding below code

```
$(document).ready( function() { 
 $.parseJSON("/blogs.json", function(data){
    var json = $.parseJSON(data);
    var blog = json.posts[0]["Blog"];   
    $.each(blog, function(){ 
      $("div#posts").append("<h1>Title: "+blog['title']+"</h1> <div class=\"post\">Content: "+blog['content']+"</div> <br />"); 
    }); 
 });
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/79wdswL7/19/)**

Comment: Still not able to get this to work with my code... any more complete example ?. Thanks, really appreciate any help on this...

Comment: Sorry i'm so new to this, what i'm trying to do is foreach 3 latest blog posts this way.

<div id="posts">
    <div class"post">
      <h1>post.title</h1>
      <p class="date">12/12/2014</p>
      <p>Post Content</p>
    </div>
</div>

Comment: My code now looks like this now

$(document).ready( function() {
    $.parseJSON("/blogs.json", function(data){
     $.each(posts[0]["Blog"], function(){
      $("div#posts").append("<h1>Title: "+blog['title']+"</h1>
                                <div class=\"post\">Content: "+blog['content']+"</div>
                                <br />");
     });
     });

Comment: Now it only outputs. "); }); });