# Overlapping tags in json

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

Having issues formatting foreach for a json, it's not opening and closing tags correctly. The code for it is below:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   $.get('/blogs.json?limit=3', function(result) {
   var posts = '';
        for (var i = 0; i < result.posts.length; i++) {
        posts += '<h3>';
        posts += '<a href="#">'+ result.posts[i].Blog.title +'</a>';
        posts += '</h3>';
        posts += ''+ result.posts[i].Blog.content +'';
        } 

    document.getElementById('bloglist').innerHTML = posts;

 });
</script>
```

And the output is messed up as it's not closing the tags etc correctly, such as

```
<h3><a href="#"></h3><p></p></h3></a> etc...
```

Any ideas why it's happening..

After investigating i see it's removing the closing tags. And it looks like this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   $.get('/blogs.json?limit=3', function(result) {
       var posts = '';
            for (var i = 0; i < result.posts.length; i++) {
            posts += '<h3>';
            posts += '<a href="#">'+ result.posts[i].Blog.title +'';
            posts += '';
            posts += '<p>'+ result.posts[i].Blog.content +'';
        } 

    document.getElementById('bloglist').innerHTML = posts;

  });
</script>
```

Comment: Can you at least show us what `blogs.json` looks like?

Comment: If you add a console.log(result.posts[i].Blog.title); at the beginning or at the end of your loop, what do you get?

Comment: Is there HTML in the JSON ? Because it isn't possible that way, you didn't define any `<p>` tag, it can't be there.

Comment: Based on the sample JSON from your [other question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25993624/jquery-get-json-values), this code is not showing the problem you describe: http://codepen.io/paulroub/pen/cFxuA - so I'll second the call for (a) the actual JSON causing the problem and (b) the actual output HTML

Comment: @PaulRoub good call there mate, hope the OP can update his question accordingly

Comment: I now see what's helping, it's removing the closing tags in the javascript for some reason, so the actual source looks like this. See above.

Comment: Please update the question with code corrections, they're obscured and hard to read in comments.

Comment: Yes, just added. For some odd reason the closing tags are removed from the javascript.

Comment: Thanks guys for the help, was able to solve this. The issue was i'm using smarty and code was within {literal} when i did the same with external javascript it worked out just fine!.